# How to encode url in javascript and decode it in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, urldecode

I have a url with querystrings through which some data are passed. I want to retrieve the data in the server side. What is the solution for this problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use javascript's  escape function to encode the URL.

```
Example : 
escape("It's me!") // result: It%27s%20me%21
```

URL Decoding in C# using Uri.UnescapeDataString() function.

```
Example : 
s = "%46%69%67%68%74%20%74%68%65%20%70%6F%77";
Uri.UnescapeDataString(s);
```

EDIT -------------------------

To Parse Query parameters in C# use

```
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks!

Hussain

Comment: my url is like this window.open ( "../EBox/ShowLetter.aspx?DocumentId="+DocumentID+"&SectionType=1&RecID="+RecipientID,'PrintMail' , features ); I want to retrieve the querystring DocumentId, SectionType,RecID. how can I get the values if the 3 querystrings

Comment: I can decode the whole url like what u said but how to get the querystrings from that

Comment: encode in javascript and to decode the url in c# and then to get the querystring values

Comment: see my updated answer. If its helpful to you then mark it as correct. :)

Comment: Beware: escape does not correctly escape all UTF-8 characters. Better to use encodeURI or encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score 4):

You can use escape ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp ) or encodeURI ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp ) to encode on Javascript side.

On server side:
For C# - Use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode to decode ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx )
For Java - Use URLDecoder to decode ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html )
For PHP - Use urldecode ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php )

Answer (score 3):

- Javascript *unescape(_stringEncoded)* same as *HttpUtility.UrlDecode(_string)* in C#
- Javascript *escape(_setringDecoded)* same as *HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_string)* in C#

[Encode/Decode both](http://www.asptricks.net/2016/03/encode-and-decode-of-string-into-both.html)

javascript Encode

```
escape('raj kumar') //raj%20kumar
```

C# Decode

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("raj%20kumar") //raj kumar
```