# Getting Javascript Error when using special characters for a parameter value in Javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following function in JavaScript, using which I call a `PageMethod` in ASP.Net.

The trouble is when I pass a string like `xy\23` or `2%` for the parameter `searchStringVal`, then I get a JavaScript error. Anyway I can handle this sort of problem? This parameter is finally passed to a static server-side method in my ASP.Net page, and this further compounds this problem. So I am looking for the most efficient approach to use in this situation.

One solution could be to encode strings in JavaScript, but I need to be able to decode it in ASP.Net C# code, without losing the original value of string.

```
function CallPageMethod(startRowIndex, searchStringVal) {        
    if (newVal != searchStringVal) {
        //document.getElementById('divMessage').style.visibility = "hidden";
        return;
    }

    start = new Date();
    PageMethods.GetData(startRowIndex, tableView.get_pageSize(), searchStringVal, updateGrid, onError, searchStringVal);
}
```

**LATEST UPDATE**: My question was answered by two different persons. How can I label both as answers? I ended up using Vinay's recommended approach of encoding in Javascript and then unecoding in C# using Uri.UnescapeDataString method.

Comment: Its a javascript error with a yellow exclamation that appears at bottom left of the browser window and when I click it says 'Unterminated String Constant'. I specified a value of 2xy\

Comment: Sunil [Refer This Link][1] Hope You are Looking for this.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613430/how-to-encode-url-in-javascript-and-decode-it-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting an unterminated string constant, then it has to do with how you're entering the string.

Typing "2xy\" is interpreted as a 2xy, and then an escaped double-quote.  The string is then underminated.

Try "2xy\\" to enter the string 2xy\ - this uses the backslash to escape the second backslash, and will be recognized as the string you're trying to enter.

Comment: How would I take care of something like 2%, as that also gives a javascript error.

Comment: What error does that give?  "2%" shouldn't give an unterminated string constant error.

Comment: I cannot see a javascript error but there seems to be some error as the page is not responding. This is when I input 2%.

Comment: Sorry - I don't think I'll be able to help track the 2% one down unless you have some more information about what's going on.  Maybe try putting a breakpoint there, and stepping through to see what's happening?

Comment: Yes I will try and let you know later. Thanks for now for your prompt help.

Comment: @Sunil your `%` issue should be URI encoding related. Refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

Comment: Eric - The % was not giving a javascript error but it was not returning valid results from database on server-side. I had an Oracle query where I used this clause: LIKE '%%%',  which is not liked by Oracle as a % needs to escaped as in LIKE '%~%%' ESCAPE '~'.

Comment: @Sunil then I expect your program to be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Alvin- I am using the parameter approach so the Oracle query looks like this: SELECT ..... from Table1 where Col1 like :MatchingContracts. I don't think with parameters SQL Injection is possible. Right?